# Mistaking versus mistaken

Tags: word-choice, past-tense

I've always been curious why some people insist that "I was mistaken" is grammatically correct whereas "I was mistaking" is grammatically wrong.  Doesn't the later follow past progressive verb tense?  Can someone give me an example where each is right or wrong?

Comment: to be mistaken; to mistake on thing for another.

Answer (score 12):

> *I was mistaking

This phrase is not a complete sentence. You would have to add *what* you were mistaking.

> I was mistaking you for a stranger, but now I found out you have been living here for three years.

Now for *mistaken*, it is used as an adjective, in the same way (and similar in meaning) as you would use *wrong*:

> I was mistaken, you are not a stranger.
>   I was wrong, you are not a stranger.

Comment: I'm not even certain `I was mistaking you for a stranger` is the correct use of the tense; I would generally expect `I had mistaken you for a stranger`. Generally, to mistake something takes only an instant, so even if someone still mistakes you for someone else, you would say `I think you've mistaken me for somebody else`. It is very rare to refer to the instant of the mistake, but perhaps `I forgive you for mistaking me for somebody else.` would work.

Comment: I mistook you for a stranger.

Comment: " the correct use of the tense" -- It can be: *When I said "The man climbing over my fence is a stranger", I was mistaking you for a stranger.*

Comment: How is "I was mistaking" an incomplete sentence, when "I was running" is not? *to run* and *to mistake* are each intransitive verbs. Certainly "mistaking" sounds odd, but that doesn't make it incorrect.

Comment: @PhilFrost: to mistake is intransitive? Can you please give an example of it being so used? I can imagine `I am running`, `I am eating`, but surely not `I am mistaking`. "So what do you do when you get home? - I read, I eat, I mistake for a while and then I sleep"??

Comment: @oerkelens I'll give you the example from [Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mistake): <you mistook when you thought I laughed at you — Thomas Hardy>

Comment: In that case I stand corrected - it appears I mistook indeed. Thank you, I was not aware of that usage. I dare say it seems highly uncommon in modern-day English though...

Comment: @oerkelens I agree. Looks like that particular example was [published in 1878](http://books.google.com/books?id=wDIZAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA739&lpg=PA739&dq=%22you+mistook+when+you+thought+I+laughed+at+you%22&q=%22you%20mistook%20when%20you%20thought%20I%20laughed%20at%20you%22#v=snippet&q=%22you%20mistook%20when%20you%20thought%20I%20laughed%20at%20you%22&f=false). I would have phrased it as "you *were wrong* when you thought I laughed at you".

Comment: *How is "I was mistaking" an incomplete sentence, when "I was running" is not?* -- By English being a natural, inconsistent language. Even your M-W example, which is never found in modern usage, is for "mistook" as meaning "was wrong". You won't find any examples of intransitive "was mistaking", as meaning "was being wrong". And even if there were such a usage, it wouldn't mean the same thing as "I was mistaken".

Answer (score 6):

In this case "mistaken" is not being used as a verb, but an adjective. In "the tall brown mistaken horse", "tall", "brown" and "mistaken" are all adjectives.

"Mistaking" can make sense, but would usually be used when you're mentioning a particular mistake you were making. "I was mistaking you for somebody that cares." Or if you'd like to refer to a single mistake rather than a habitual one, "I mistook you for somebody that cares." Or, sticking with mistaken, "I was mistaken in thinking you were somebody that cares."

Answer (score 5):

Both constructions are grammatical, but only one is also idiomatic.

With the meaning "I was wrong", only "I was mistaken" is used. "I was mistaking" could be easily encountered in a different context, though: "I was mistaking X for Y". There, in turn, "I was mistaken" wouldn't be possible.

There is actually a name for this linguistic phenomenon: [*blocking*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocking_%28linguistics%29). When two theoretically equally valid ways of saying something conflict, the existence of one blocks the other from getting any traction.

Comment: "I was mistaking" is not a complete sentence, any more than "I was replacing". As tobyink notes, "mistaken" is an adjective, not a verb.

Comment: @Jim I never said it was a complete sentence, and neither did the OP. I am answering the question at face value. (And by the way, just because a sentence is nonsensical, doesn't make it incomplete. But again, that's beside the point here.) I also never said "mistaken" was a verb. **Edit:** In fact, my answer is all but identical to tobyink's and oerkelens'.

Comment: *I never said it was a complete sentence,  and neither did the OP.* -- Irrelevant strawman; the OP offered it as a complete sentence, as a substitute for "I was mistaken". As such, it's ungrammatical, and certainly not "theoretically equally valid". *I also never said "mistaken" was a verb.* -- Irrelevant strawman. I didn't say you said it, *I* said it. I said it because it's relevant, as the OP asked about verb tense. *my answer is all but identical to tobyink's and oerkelens* -- this is flat out obviously not true.

Answer (score 5):

I have a slightly different resolution to this conflict from the other answers, although I agree with them as well.

There are two related verb phrases:

(1) "to mistake [object] for [second object]" [meaning: to erroneously think that object 1 is object 2]."

and the more common

(2) "to make a mistake." [meaning: to err.]

The reason you cannot say "I was mistaking" is because the verb "to mistake" as in (1) is transitive. (In fact, semantically it must take two objects, separated by the word "for.")

The phrase "I was mistaken" refers always and only to the second of these. If you wanted to use the past progressive, you could certainly say "I was making a mistake." (This is exactly taking the verb in (2) and turning it into a past progressive form, which is what you wanted to do with the verb in (1), but which you were told not to do). It means more or less the same thing as "I was mistaken," but emphasizes the process more, as is what you would expect from the past progressive.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Jim Balter. Past progressive is usually used to describe two actions that happen at the same time.

"When the typhoon came, I was walking on the beach."

"I was blowing out the candles on my birthday cake as my long lost friend walked in."

"When I kissed you, I was mistaking you for my wife."

It still sounds awkward however.

Answer (score 0):

Mistaken is a past participle, and in "I am mistaken," it is used correctly as a predicate adjective.  Parallels:  I am hurt, I am bundled up, I was seated late, she is well brought up, etc.

In the case of "I am mistaking," the verb "to mistake" is transitive--that is, it requires a direct object [D.O.], much as "to kick" or "to thank" require direct objects.  I must mistake something, kick something, thank something/someone.  "I am mistaking you [D.O.] for someone else" or "I was mistaking him [D.O.] for his twin brother" are fine (and tense makes no difference),but we need that direct object in there.

Some verbs may be transitive or intransitive:  I eat Kit-Kats [D.O.] vs. I eat [no D.O.] at 6:30.  Others are only transitive or only intransitive.

Answer (score 0):

There are two forms here. This is very simple. I simply can't read through the answers that are so long.

**To be mistaken [about someone or something]** Compare that to:

**To mistake** one thing or person for another. [a transitive verb]

He was mistaken for a famous actor [by the girl].

She mistook him for a famous actor.

They both mean the same thing.

Answer (score -2):

I was mistaking sounds like I was in the act of making a mistake.

I was mistaken sounds like I was the object of someone else's mistake.